# Reflection for testNG

Tags: java, spring, reflection, spring-security, testng

I have a method which uses to restrict the access via spring security. The following is the method :

```
@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated() and hasPermission(#request, 'CREATE_REQUISITION')")
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/trade/createrequisition")
    public @ResponseBody
    void createRequisition(@RequestBody CreateRequisitionRO[] request,
            @RequestHeader("validateOnly") boolean validateOnly) {
        logger.debug("Starting createRequisition()...");
        for (int i = 0; i < request.length; i++) {
            CreateRequisitionRO requisitionRequest = request[i];

            // FIXME this has to be removed/moved
            requisitionRequest.setFundManager(requisitionRequest.getUserId());
            // FIXME might have to search using param level as well
            SystemDefault sysDefault = dbFuncs.references.systemDefault
                    .findByCompanyAndDivisionAndPortfolio(
                            userContext.getCompany(),
                            userContext.getDivision(),
                            requisitionRequest.getPortfolio());
            requisitionRequest.setCustodianN(sysDefault.getCustodianN());

            gateKeeper.route(requisitionRequest);
        }
    }
```

Now i want to use java Reflection at run time to test whether the method is working fine like unit testing.

I have tried to write TestNG for the above which is not working due to the project architecture we have and hence decided to use reflection to test `[though which is not a good way of doing this and later we will find the solution for this]`.

My question is how to create a java reflection class for that method and call the above method and send the URL `/trade/createrequisition` to server whether it is accessible for the logged in user.

How to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check if the security annotation is added on the method then in unit test case using java reflection API you can do that.

Find the method using reflection and on that check method.getAnnotation(PreAuthorize.class)

But actually you should test this as a Integration/Functional testing.